# Yii variable used in another function? How to implement except session?

Tags: php, yii

I am using some variables in a Yii controller action. Now I want to validate it in another action of the same controller where I am getting the server response. I don't want to use session method. Is there any other way to implement my goal?
one of my action is request and the other is server response handling action.

Comment: Not familiar with Yii, but if your actions are methods inside a controller class, and the methods are called in the same HTTP request, then you could use class attributes (`$this->myValue = $value;`). However, if your actions are in different requests, then sessions would be the way to go.

Comment: What do you mean "cross check"? Code please.